White seams on low poly model
So I've been trying to make a low-poly model in Blender, and I'm working on the textures. However the textures along the seams I used to unwrap it are missing, I have so far not been able to figure out a solution. I've already tried changing the size of the UVs, re-wrapping and changing the size of the margins, and marking the seams as sharp edges. Otherwise I have not been able to find any other solutions here or elsewhere on the internet.
NOTES:
I thought I'd put this here for a little bit more clarification based on the first comment I got here.
"We need to see settings in your paint tool - are you using the Fill tool or the Brush tool,-"
Fill tool, but I've also tried to use the brush tool to fix it to no avail.
"-Are you using the Face Select Masking setting,-"
I'm not, I've tried doing that for certain other parts that will be a different color with similar results.
"-Are you using Cavity masking,-"
Don't even know what that is so no Cavity masking.
 

We need to see settings in your paint tool - are you using the Fill tool or the Brush tool, are you using the Face Select Masking setting, are you using Cavity masking, are you able to paint in the 2d editor to resolve the issue in the 3d view or is it the same exact thing coming back? Can you instead set material colors to faces first and bake that as a texture to then paint on in a single material? Have you seen similar issues before with a less complex form?


Fill tool, but I've also tried to use the brush tool to fix it to no avail.
I'm not, I've tried doing that for certain other parts that will be a different color with similar results.
Don't even know what that is so no Cavity masking.
I have not tried to painting in 2d but I'll get back to you on that.
How would I go about changing material settings? Or baking the textures?
See no.2, I had also experienced an issue with white lines dotted around a section of the model I made separately but that was a materials issue and I have already solved that problem.


As for me here, the only way I get that same behavior that I use a Fill too oand a space appears at the joined area and that a Brush tool can't fix is a Cavity Mask turned on. See the screenshot for the location in 4.1 for this - possibly a random key combination could have turned it on maybe. Check your file to see if it is on in your session.


Don't use 4.1, still on 3.6. but I did find the option in the tool settings and the option wasn't turned on. But some other masking option is on called stencil mask, would that be causing it?

Yes, that very well could be causing it as it enables a texture image to be used as a mask. Did turning it off resolve the paint issue

Sadly it does not, plus I've tested it with and without the stencil mask and there is no visible difference between the two.
